# 'If'Statement being ignored when setting UITableView sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have been having issues with an 'if' statement being ignored when defining a section's title with multiple `UITableView`s. What's happening is on both UITableViews it's displaying 'Switzerland'. Code below - can you explain what's wrong?? I have tried `else if`, and `if`, non of which work.

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ((tableView=_listTableView)) {

        //if(section == 0) {
        return @"Switzerland";
        //}
    }
    else {
       // if(section == 0) {
            return @"A";
}
return 0;

}
```

Cheers,
SebOH

Comment: `=` should be `==` on your first `if` statement

Comment: = is assignment operator and not used for comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to compare two object use == instead of just one =:

```
if ((tableView==_listTableView)) {
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace `=` with `==` in `if ((tableView=_listTableView))`

#### Explanation

`=` is an assignment operator, so `_listTableView` will be assigned to `tableView` and the `if` conditions is evaluated as `if(tableView)`, which always returns true, unless, your `_listTableView` is null

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, considering the explanation as to **why** the OP should use `==` instead of `=`.